# Laravel search in relation by 2 values

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with my Laravel app.
I'm trying to make a query that will get all results from one model, and inside I have relation that will need to make a query that depends on 2 values, those values can be an array. So to celarify the problem, let's see some code.

I have object that looks like:

```
    [{
        "id": "24b16d30-884a-4b3d-b535-77af540b5f5c",
        "product_id": "69292b28-773c-4223-b480-d39020602b52",
        "qty": 4,
    },
    {
        "id": "622bc183-1243-4104-98e6-1820949305fb",
        "product_id": "10c19e8d-89b3-480f-a83b-7185cc7ba0fe",
        "qty": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": "c7f03f06-01d1-4cd0-bafb-03308feb8644",
        "product_id": "7765a4c7-37b1-4591-bbcb-095aa06a3455",
        "qty": 451,
 
    }]
```

So this object is used to make a query, I need to check where query has this product_id and qty more then this value.

So far I successfully made query that is taking only by product_id, but I don't know how to check the stock quantity. And it looks like this

```
$findFF = Fulfillments::with(['stock' => function ($q) use ($get_products){

        $q_products = [];
        $q_stock = [];

        foreach ($get_products as $key => $product){
               array_push($q_products, $product['product_id']);
               array_push($q_stock, $product['qty']);
        }

        $q->whereIn('product_id', $q_products);

}])->get();
```

have in mind that `$get_products` are actually the first object I explained.

It's maybe not best way to make this query, I could pluck them, but I can't pluck with 2 values. I just need to check if this product has more qty then given value. And it should look like:

```
$q->whereIn('stock_qty', $q_stock);
```

or

```
$q->whereIn('product_id', $q_products)->whereIn('stock_qty', $q_stock);
```

But it will not depend on product_id, and it's not gonna be correct.

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

To get entries matching to your array just select only `stock` with matching to both condition like this:

```php
Fulfillments::whereHas('stocks', function ($q) use ($get_products){
    foreach ($get_products as $product){
        $q->orWhere( function($q) use ($product) {
            $q->where('product_id', '=', $product['product_id'])
              ->where('qty', '>', $product['qty']);
        });
    }
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But in this case it will give me everything, I just tried it.

Comment: Just to be sure that i understand correctly. You want to get Fullfilmets which stocks match to array or all Fulfillments with matching stocks ?

Comment: Well fullfilments stock must be more than array value. For example if fulfillment stock is 5, and array value (qty) is 6 it will not display, if it's 4 it will display. In your code, it's giving all products, it's not matching them as well.

Comment: I saw the edit, it's still giving all products :/ not given ones

Comment: I made two edits, did you try second or only first ?

Comment: Yes, and it's not returning stock now :/ it's not giving an error, but it must has with('stock'), in that case it's whereHas

Comment: I still have faith in the first code that you give, but I can't understand why it's not matching products, I think orWhere function is not correct in that case

Comment: Actually whereIn is a correct function, but I have no idea how to use it in that case